# After OneSignal installation, cannot find module '@ionic-native/onesignal'. error in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

I have a strange error on an ionic project with OneSignal. I have installed [OneSignal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/) with these commands

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```

to my project. However, after the installation, I am taking this error:

[image]

After that, I have installed again it, but there is still again the error. I think that because of this, OneSignal is not working on my project.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Sometime the tutorials aren't helpful especially when they miss important steps.
Try running this on your cli:

```
sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```

Or, trying installing it as a global plug in.

A coupe of tutorials I've looked at and compared are:

https://www.ghadeer.io/ionic-3-push-notifications-one-signal/

https://medium.com/appseed-io/how-to-integrate-onesignal-push-notifications-into-an-ionic-3-application-eb2fdc3e6176

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem and added the solution.

Comment: No problems. I think I may have even seen your reply after I hit submit. Glad it's working too though.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with changing the versions of node-sass and node. The problem is from the incompatibility of `node-sass` and `node` with OneSignal.

Firstly, you need to check your node-sass version with `npm node-sass -v` and then, check your node version with `node -v`. After that, go to [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases) and compare your node-sass and node version on Supported Environments. If they are incompatible, you should downgrade or upgrade your node-sass or node. Finally, you need to install again OneSignal with these commands

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal
```